# How to make an slider in HTML, Javascript and Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Hello I have a simple slider made in HTML and CSS which works perfectly. But I don't know how to implement it in JavaScript and show it in a real-time database in firebase. So the question is: What I have to do in JavaScript related to the movement of the simple slider? And how it will response in the database?. Thank You.

Code In javascript of the slider:

```
 function guid() {
  function s4() {
    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
      .toString(16)
      .substring(1);
  }
  return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
    s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

function outputUpdate(v) {
  fb.push({id: id, position: v});
  id++;
}

var id = 1;
var currentdate = new Date();
var uuid = guid();
var fb = new Firebase("link firebase" + uuid + "DAY-" + currentdate.getDate() + "-" + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)
 + "TIME-" + currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + currentdate.getSeconds());
});
```

Codigo del slider en HTML:

```
 <label for= "happiness">  </label><input name="happiness" id="slider1" type= "range" min="0" max="100" value="50" id="happiness" step="25"
        onchange="outputUpdate(value)"><output for="happiness" name= "level"></output>
```

I would like to know if it is another way to do that or what is wrong with it because it didn't work, and if someone has an example of an slider with these features, I will appreciate if he/she share it with me. Thank you again.

Comment: ...and what have you tried?

Comment: is your slider made using jQuery UI? other library?

Comment: Showing us the code for your slider would be a good start